# How to perform action after JFrame is closed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I need to perform an action after the JFrame is closed and I have this part of code for it, but this doesn't work.

Could anyone please advise what should be change here?

```
private void changeDefaults(){
    Thread changeDefaultsThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Change ch = new Change();
            ch.setVisible(true);
            ch.setListeners();
            ch.defaultInput();
            while(ch.isActive()){
                System.out.println("active");
            }
            updateDefaults();
            }
    });
    changeDefaultsThread.start();
}
```

Change is the JFrame I am opening for another action.

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? What happens? What is the error message?

Comment: It is likely the frame had a close operation that ended the VM on frame close.  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned the simplest solution: **don't** use a JFrame. The best tool for this behavior -- displaying a child window and doing something immediately after it has closed -- is to use a modal dialog window such as a JDialog or JOptionPane. The JDialog set up code is *very* similar to that of the JFrame, with an exception being that it uses different constructors, and should have the parent window passed into it, and it uses a subset of the default close operations.

If you use a modal dialog, then program flow is halted in the calling code immediately after the dialog has been displayed (think of how a JOptionPane operates), and then immediately resumes from the spot after calling `setVisible(true)` on the dialog once the dialog has been closed.

The only bugaboo is that if you don't want modal behavior -- if you don't want the parent/calling window to be disabled while the child window is displayed -- then you'll have to use a non-modal JDialog window with a WindowListener.

Answer (score 2):

You can add listener to your JFrame

```
frame.addWindowListener (new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter)
```

and override the windowClosing

```
 @Override
 public void windowClosing
```

---

```
frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: About this solution I have an issue. The issue is that I don't know how can I call method of the main frame from the second one.

Comment: You can pass an instance of main frame to second one using constructor and from within windowClosing can call.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an action when closing a JFrame, you just need to attach a WindowListener (extending WindowAdapter so that you do not need to implement all WindowListener methods):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class AfterJFrameClose {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                System.out.println("Frame closing");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Instead of the System.out.println, just write the code you want to have executed.

Update: If you want to access another frame, you either should pass it as a parameter as suggested above or you can also iterate through active frames using something like this:

```
Frame[] frames = Frame.getFrames();
for (Frame frame: frames) {
    System.out.println(frame.getTitle());
}
```